# extraction of certain rows between two consecutive blank rows to a single column in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. I have a table having only one column but many rows. I need to extract certain rows between two consecutive blank rows to a single column. 
Or need to extract rows between two strings at two different rows.
I do not know how to do that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include sample data, expected output and the code you have tried. See: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Don't expect a fully written code when you have not even given time to frame the question well!! Thanks

Comment: You are very unprecise with your language. Please clarify: `"table"` you probably mean a `data.frame` or `matrix`. `"blank rows"` do you mean an empty string `""` or a missing value `NA`? `"extract rows between two strings at two different rows"` that's very broad. You tell nothing about the characteristics/form of the string.

Comment: In any case. Your question can be solved with `regular expressions` and `?grepl`.

Answer (score 1):

To subset column in between two strings between you can use the following approach (`gsub` and `data.frame` subsetting):

```
df <- data.frame(foo = c("X","", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "", "E"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#    foo
# 1   X
# 2    
# 3   A
# 4   B
# 5   C
# 6   D
# 7   A
# 8    
# 9   E

# empty string
empty_between <- grep("^$", df$foo)
df[(empty_between[1] + 1):(empty_between[2] - 1), , drop = FALSE]
#    foo
# 3   A
# 4   B
# 5   C
# 6   D
# 7   A

# between two strings (in this case "A")
string_between <- grep("^A$", df$foo)
df[(string_between[1] + 1):(string_between[2] - 1), , drop = FALSE]
#    foo
# 4   B
# 5   C
# 6   D
```